# What is Init display first?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios

What is Init display first in bios setting?
.I'm afraid to change that option
Which better PCI or PEG?
[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

The Init display function in the BIOS will initialize your graphics card as soon as the computer is woken up, rather than let it be resumed by your operating system. Some graphics cards require this or the system will freeze when you put the computer in a low powerstate such as S3 or S5. Especially with older graphicscards, Windows is known to BSoD when putting the system to standby in a lower powerstate where power is only sent to the memory and not the rest. When the system is woken up, the grapics card is assumed to be present, but due to the low powerstate, is not yet available when Windows wants to resume graphics, and thus the system crashes.

By enabling this setting in the bios, upon resuming from standby, the BIOS waits a little bit and sends an init signal to the graphics card before handing the init routine back to the OS.

If you select PCI, onboard graphics will be initialized first, whereas if you choose PEG, the PCI-Express Graphics adapter will be initialized first, aka the graphics card that was installed in the PCI-Express slot.

They will both be initialized, its just that if you use a PCI-Express graphics card, changing this to PEG will allow you to see the display faster.

Comment: I don’t know that I have PCI Express graphic card. I just have an old graphic card(ATI RADEON HD4550 series).indeed I didn’t understand what you said(difference between pci and peg).Because I can’t read English title very well and I just can simply word and title in English .However thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: you'll want the PEG one.